# Data structure / algorithm design for insertion

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose you have a line object that holds a value and a length. How to design a data structure such that whenever you insert a new line object, it will not only store it but also return the sum of values of every line object that has a shorter length than the new line object. The time complexity for each insertion should be O(logn). The overall time complexity can be O(nlogn).

I have tried to use segment tree but am a bit confused about how to adjust it to solve my issue. Since I think the segment tree itself doesn't really help me to filter only line objects that have shorter length than the new inserted line object.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to sort them? Is keeping them in sorted order considered sorting? If so, what about storing them in a fixed permutation of sorted order to circumevent this requirement?

Comment: Sorry I have edited a little bit because the original one was a bit off what I actually want to ask, there isn't any restriction to sorting

Comment: Then use binary search (based on length) to find where to insert, this is O(log n)

Comment: so I should still use segment tree data structure and then binary search to find the insertion place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), using the length attribute as key, and value as payload. For example, you could use an AVL tree, or a red-black tree.

In addition to the length and value attributes of a node, you would also maintain a total of all values in the node's descendants, including its own value.

This means that for an insert operation, while you walk down the tree to find the insertion spot, you should update the total value in each node you visit, adding to it the value to be inserted.

Also, while walking down the tree, accumulate the sum that should be returned as follows:

When going to the right, add to the sum the total value stored in the parent you come from (and before it was increased), and subtract the total value stored in the child you are moving to (also before it is increased).

When going to the left, do not alter the sum.

When finally inserting the leaf, the same rule applies. When inserting it as a right child, then the sum should be increased with the total value of its parent (before it was increased). If the leaf becomes a left child, do not alter the sum.

Return the sum.

Take care of the self-balancing mechanism (depending on the type of self-balancing tree you opt for): when a rotation is needed, the total values stored in the impacted nodes need to be adjusted as well. But this should not be difficult to manage.